# Haml Pipe Separated Multiline Statement Syntax Highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, textmate, textmatebundles

How do I eradicate this kind of ugliness?

[image]

Would be nice to have some syntax highlighting on this stuff.

I thought this Textmate bundle [here](https://github.com/handcrafted/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle) might do the trick, but no luck. I know it's all to do with the pipe separators for multiline statements.

Answer (score 1):

Do you even need those vertical bars in the first place?  I have never used them in this way in my Haml files.  According to the Haml docs, [the pipe character designates a multiline string](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#multiline):

```
%whoo
  %hoo= h(                       |
    "I think this might get " +  |
    "pretty long so I should " + |
    "probably make it " +        |
    "multiline so it doesn't " + |
    "look awful.")               |
  %p This is short.
```

So, for what you are doing, just having a comma at the end of the line after one of your arguments should be enough to put the next argument wherever you would like on the next line.

Comment: good point. i was getting errors before, i'll have to revisit and see what the error was. thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Did getting rid of the lines end up fixing the errors you were getting, or at least give you the same errors, yet now you have prettier code? :-)